# How can i hide/disable my radio button once one is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to disable or hide the radio button once one has been selected - this is so that the user can t price compare as the radio button is linked to the price and shows the price once the radio button is checked.  I am using knockout.js to link the selected radio button and display the price.  And  have found a way on jquery to hide the not selected radio buttons but I am having trouble merging the two together.

Please see the code below:

```
<div class="stepTwo">
    <div class="middleTitle">
        <p>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="with: bin2ViewModel">
        <div class="divRadiobtns" data-bind="foreach: availableGroups">
            <input type="radio" id="makeOpacityHide" class="radioOptions" name="retailerGroup"
                data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedGroupOption, value: retailerproductId" /><span
                    class="radioOptionsA" data-bind="css: { 'radioOptionsA-checked': $parent.selectedGroupOption()==retailerproductId() }">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="with: selectedRetailerGroup">
            <span class="actualPrice" data-bind="text: price" />
        </div>
        <div data-bind="with: selectedRetailerGroup">
            <input type="hidden" name="retailerProductId" id="retailerProductId" class="retailerProductId"
                data-bind="value: retailerproductId" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    //jquery
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name$='retailerGroup']").click(function () {
            var test = $(this).val();

            $("input.radioOptionsA").hide();

        });
    });


    //knockout
    var Bin2ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        this.selectedRetailerGroup = ko.observable();
        this.selectedGroupOption = ko.observable();
        this.selectedGroupOption.subscribe(function (newVal) {
            var items = $.grep(self.availableGroups(), function (item) { return item.retailerproductId() == newVal; });
            self.selectedRetailerGroup(items[0]);
        });
        this.selectedGroup = ko.observable();
        this.availableGroups = ko.observableArray(
            [new RetailerViewModel("21290", "£1.80"),
                new RetailerViewModel("302852", "£2.55"),
                new RetailerViewModel("422974", "£2.55")
            ]);
    };


    var RetailerViewModel = function (retailerproductId, price) {
        this.retailerproductId = ko.observable(retailerproductId);
        this.price = ko.observable(price);
    };
    ko.applyBindings({ bin2ViewModel: ko.observable(new Bin2ViewModel()) });
//]]>
</script>
```

Does anyone know a way of making them work toether or is there a good way to hide the radio buttons in knockout?

http://jsfiddle.net/afnguyen/MMqzv/3/

I have also attached the jquery in a jsfiddle  - this shows what i want as the selected radio button class name changes and so should not hide:

http://jsfiddle.net/afnguyen/5mmt2/1/

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind providing a jsFiddle?

Comment: How about $(this).hide();

Comment: @Chazt3n i have added a fiddle

Comment: @mplungjan i think that is what i have tried to do:

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
                                $("input[name$='retailerGroup']").click(function () {
                                    var test = $(this).val();

                                    $("input.radioOptionsA").hide();

                                });
                            });

Comment: Ok thank you, looks good btw. Just for clarification, you want the one you clicked on the left to be hidden?

Comment: @Chazt3n no its the unchecked ones I want to hide - so the one that is checked is left visible.  Thanks

Comment: Note that users can get around this by loading multiple versions of the page.  You're just making the price comparison a bit more difficult.  You're also making things more annoying for people who mis-click the first time.

Comment: @Ben Barden its what the client has requested - i think when they see it they may decide to go back - we have explained this to them - they can refresh the page etc and see another price...i agree not the best user experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can change the css attrib "disabled" to = "disabled":

```
    $(".class").attr(
        'disabled', 'disabled'
    );
```

Comment: Hi thanks that has worked i've updated my fiddler with your change http://jsfiddle.net/afnguyen/MMqzv/10/ Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a pure Kncokout solution you can achieve the same effect with the help of the [enable binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html):

So you want to enable the button when none of them selected which translates the following binding:

```
data-bind="enable: !$parent.selectedGroupOption()"
```

So the full sample with your code:

```
<input type="radio" id="makeOpacityHide" 
       class="radioOptions" name="retailerGroup"
       data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedGroupOption, 
                  value: retailerproductId, 
                  enable: !$parent.selectedGroupOption()" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jT2fU/1/).

Comment: very nice - its probably better to stick to knockout rather than swapping! thanks